# ClickOnce preserve LAA flag after signing

Tags: clickonce

In my ClickOnce application I use the following events to set the LAA flag en resign the application.
The sign event seems to remove the LAA flag. Without the sign event the application has the LAA flag but isn't correctly signed.

```
  <Target Name="AfterCompile">
    <Exec Command="call &quot;$(TargetDir)editbin.exe&quot; /largeaddressaware &quot;$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName)&quot;" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterCompile">
    <Exec Command="&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\SignTool.exe&quot; sign /f &quot;cert.pfx&quot; /p certpw /v &quot;$(ProjectDir)obj/$(ConfigurationName)/$(TargetFileName)&quot;" />
  </Target>
```

How can the flag be preserved? Do I need to use other build events? I know that x64 is the best option here, but for now that's not possible.